# DataTables Group Select/Deselect

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I am trying to figure out how to create a group select/deselect in datatables.  Each row in the table is tagged with a group (integer), for any given selection it should select/deselect all other items with that same group number.  I feel like I'm pretty close with the code below...BUT, unfortunately as I select the related rows they in turn fire the select event and it's an endless loop   I was playing around with e.preventDefault() but that didn't seem to help.  Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
     table.on("select", function(e, dt, type, indexes) {

            var data = table.rows(indexes).data();
            var group = data[0]['Group'];

            table.rows(function(idx, rowData, node) {
                return rowData.Group === group;
            }).select();

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detach event handler before selecting other rows and re-attach it after the selection as shown below:

```js
function onSelect(e, dt, type, indexes){
    var data = dt.rows(indexes).data();
    var group = data[0]['Group'];

    // Detach event hanlder
    dt.off('select', onSelect);

    dt.rows(function(idx, rowData, node) {
        return rowData.Group === group;
    }).select();

    // Re-attach event hanlder
    dt.on('select', onSelect);
});

table.on('select', onSelect);
```

You can also use a global variable, for example:

```js
var ignoreSelect = false;
table.on("select", function(e, dt, type, indexes) {
   if(ignoreSelect){ return; }

   var data = dt.rows(indexes).data();
   var group = data[0]['Group'];

   ignoreSelect = true;

   dt.rows(function(idx, rowData, node) {
      return rowData.Group === group;
   }).select();

   ignoreSelect = false;
});
```

Comment: thanks!  Seems so straight...hard to believe I didn't think of any of these options.